# Bash script while condition fail to work

Tags: bash

I'm new to bash script.  I wrote this small script today.  When I run it, it returns error: ./test1.sh: line 8: [n != y]]: command not found.  I've tried several different combinations and can't get it to work.

```
#!/bin/bash

function ask_yes_or_no
{
  local exitLoop="n"
  local answer=""
  while ["$exitLoop" != "y"]]
    do
      read -p "$1 (y/n)? " choice
      case "$choice" in 
        y|Y ) 
          answer="y"
          exitLoop="y"
          ;;
        n|N ) 
          answer="y"
          exitLoop="y"
          ;;
      esac
    done

  echo $answer
}

retVal=$(ask_yes_or_no "Do you want to continue")

echo $retVal;

exit 0
```

Comment: The while loop has 2 ending ]] it should be only ], in addition there are spaces, this is very important: **while [ "$exitLoop" != "y" ]**

Comment: Function definition should be **function ask_yes_or_no()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put all together the remarks in my comment, and with help of [shellcheck online](http://www.shellcheck.net/), there is below a first version:

```
#!/bin/bash --

function ask_yes_or_no() 
{
  local exitLoop="n"
  local answer=""
  while [ "$exitLoop" != "y" ]
  do
    read -r -p "$1 (y/n)? " choice
    case "$choice" in
      y|Y )
        answer="y"
        exitLoop="y"
        ;;
      n|N )
        answer="n"
        exitLoop="y"
        ;;
    esac
  done

  echo $answer
}

retVal=$(ask_yes_or_no "Do you want to continue")

echo "$retVal";

exit 0
```

So, your very first try is almost good. As written in the comment, there was 2 ending ]] instead of ] in the **while** condition, and there are important **space** chars to add. The rest is from shellcheck (which can be installed as a command line).

The test is below:

```
chmod +x ./myscript.sh
./myscript.sh
Do you want to continue (y/n)? y
y
./myscript.sh
Do you want to continue (y/n)? n
n
```

Comment: Thanks Jay.  That work.  I'll never suspect those extra spaces will cause it to error out.  That is one strange syntax.